# how to redirect multiple file with the help of .htaccess in php

Tags: php, .htaccess

```html
<!-- multiple redirection of file  is not working -->
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ category.php?catname=$1 [L,N]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ fullview.php?view=$1 [L]
<!--end -->
```

Comment: "Not working" is a really broad description of your problem. What exactly is not working?

Answer (score 0):

**Just replace you root folder**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /Your root folder name
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```